# Possible to connect non-local rasberri pis to create mesh network?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Hello I am new to Raspberry Pi's and need to use them for my school project. Each of my group members were given one raspberry pi from the school, and we wanted to make a mesh network with them for our project.

We know it is possible to create a mesh network if all the devices are on the same Wi-Fi network, but we do not live close to each other and only go into school once a week.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to connect the raspberry pi's into a mesh network when they are not in close proximity to one another? So that we can work with out mesh network from our homes while not at school?

Thanks

Comment: this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question ... perhaps a Linux question ... definitely a networking question

Comment: research in the realm of VPN

Comment: Depends what you mean by "a mesh network"

Comment: Check out a tool like Tailscale: https://tailscale.com/